# Deployment error after upgrade to Xcode 10.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Upgrade my Mac to MacOS 10.14.5, Upgrade Xcode to 10.2.1 and now i can't deploy my projects on emulators and on real devices.

> Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac Version 7.6.5 (build 20)
>
> Runtime:  Mono
> 5.12.0.301 (2018-02/4fe3280bba1) (64-bit)     GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)    Xamarin.Mac 4.4.1.178 (master / eeaeb7e6)
>
> Package version: 512000301
>
> Apple Developer Tools Xcode 10.2.1 (14490.122) Build 10E1001
>
> Xamarin.Mac Version: 4.6.0.14 (Visual Studio Community) Hash: 1a6e2786
> Branch:  Build date: 2018-08-28 00:12:06-0400
>
> Xamarin.iOS Version: 11.14.0.14 (Visual Studio Community) Hash:
> 1a6e2786 Branch: HEAD Build date: 2018-08-28 00:12:06-0400

Here is my deployment error log

```
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mlaunch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" --installdev "/Users/dev/Desktop/My Projects/Gefsinus/TapNOrderIOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone6.2-12.1.4/TapNOrder.app" --device ios "--devname=Emmanouil’s iPhone" --install-progress
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs18__stdlib_AtomicInt is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55a10c8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x112279158). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs19__EmptyArrayStorage is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55931e0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b268). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCVVs17__CocoaDictionary5Index7Storage is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55a1258) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x1122792e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCVs17__CocoaDictionary8Iterator is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55a1310) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x1122793a0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs22__RawDictionaryStorage is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593290) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs26__EmptyDictionarySingleton is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593348) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b3d0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs24__SwiftEmptyNSEnumerator is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593408) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b490). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs11_AnyKeyPath is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55a1538) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x1122795c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs20__SwiftNativeNSArray is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593470) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b4f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs25__SwiftNativeNSDictionary is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55934d8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b560). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs18__SwiftNativeNSSet is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593540) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b5c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs25__SwiftNativeNSEnumerator is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55935a8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b630). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs19__SwiftNativeNSData is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593610) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b698). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs32__stdlib_ReturnAutoreleasedDummy is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593678) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b700). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCVVs10__CocoaSet5Index7Storage is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55a1690) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x112279720). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCVs10__CocoaSet8Iterator is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55a1748) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x1122797d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs15__RawSetStorage is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55936e0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b768). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs19__EmptySetSingleton is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593790) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b818). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs18_StringBreadcrumbs is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55a1850) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x1122798e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs21__SwiftNativeNSString is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593848) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b8d0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs15__StringStorage is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55938b0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b938). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs21__SharedStringStorage is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593930) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226b9b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs41__SwiftNativeNSArrayWithContiguousStorage is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55939c0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226ba48). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs22__SwiftDeferredNSArray is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593a30) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226bab8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs28__ContiguousArrayStorageBase is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593ab8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226bb40). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs15__VaListBuilder is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa55a19c0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x112279a50). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class __SwiftNativeNSError is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593b50) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226bbd8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class _TtCs12_SwiftObject is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593ba0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226bc28). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class __SwiftValue is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593c18) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226bca0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class __SwiftNull is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593c68) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226bcf0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class __SwiftNativeNSArrayBase is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593cb8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226bd40). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class __SwiftNativeNSDictionaryBase is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593d08) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226bd90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class __SwiftNativeNSSetBase is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593d58) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226bde0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class __SwiftNativeNSStringBase is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593da8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226be30). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class __SwiftNativeNSEnumeratorBase is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593df8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226be80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class __SwiftNativeNSDataBase is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593e48) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226bed0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1639]: Class __SwiftNativeNSIndexSetBase is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fffa5593e98) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x11226bf20). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 10.14.4.
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn._dlopen (string,int) [0x00014] in <17ce5e57d7854eaebabaf5a28945d061>:0
  at ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn.dlopen (string,int) [0x00001] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/4.6.0.14/src/Xamarin.Mac/ObjCRuntime/Dlfcn.cs:93
  at Xamarin.Hosting.Services.LoadFramework (string,bool) [0x00044] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/maciostools/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Hosting/Services.cs:233
  at Xamarin.Hosting.Services.LoadFrameworks () [0x0011c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/maciostools/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Hosting/Services.cs:136
  at Xamarin.Hosting.Services.Initialize (string,bool) [0x000e7] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/maciostools/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Hosting/Services.cs:102
  at Xamarin.Launcher.DevController.Initialize () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/maciostools/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Launcher/controller-device.cs:35
  at Xamarin.Launcher.DevController/<InstallApplicationAsync>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00066] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/maciostools/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Launcher/controller-device.cs:73
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<TStateMachine_REF> (TStateMachine_REF&) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/4.6.0.14/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:316
  at Xamarin.Launcher.DevController.InstallApplicationAsync (string,string,string) [0x00038] in <4309e8c26f834115a4dd8fcefb457162>:0
  at Xamarin.Launcher.Driver/<MainAsync>d__56.MoveNext () [0x00256] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/maciostools/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Launcher/Main.cs:459
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int>.Start<Xamarin.Launcher.Driver/<MainAsync>d__56> (Xamarin.Launcher.Driver/<MainAsync>d__56&) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/4.6.0.14/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:471
  at Xamarin.Launcher.Driver.MainAsync () [0x00023] in <4309e8c26f834115a4dd8fcefb457162>:0
  at Xamarin.Launcher.Driver.Main2 (string[]) [0x00af2] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/maciostools/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Launcher/Main.cs:446
  at Xamarin.Launcher.Driver.Main (string[]) [0x0006d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/maciostools/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Launcher/Main.cs:147
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_int_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00057] in <4309e8c26f834115a4dd8fcefb457162>:0

Native stacktrace:

    0   mlaunch                             0x000000010b4f3408 mono_handle_native_crash + 264
    1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff6eeeab5d _sigtramp + 29
    2   ???                                 0x00007ffee4829a60 0x0 + 140732732185184
    3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff6eda46a6 abort + 127
    4   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x00000001121aab05 _ZN5swift10fatalErrorEjPKcz + 149
    5   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x00000001121a26df _ZL12checkVersionv + 47
    6   ???                                 0x0000000111d22592 0x0 + 4593952146
    7   ???                                 0x0000000111d22798 0x0 + 4593952664
    8   ???                                 0x0000000111d1dbea 0x0 + 4593933290
    9   ???                                 0x0000000111d1cd73 0x0 + 4593929587
    10  ???                                 0x0000000111d1ce05 0x0 + 4593929733
    11  ???                                 0x0000000111d0fcb2 0x0 + 4593876146
Entering thread summarizer from 4594517440
    12  ???                                 0x0000000111d193dc 0x0 + 4593914844
    13  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6ecead43 dlopen + 200
    14  ???                                 0x000000010fcb5634 0x0 + 4559951412
    15  ???                                 0x00000001102e7a91 0x0 + 4566448785
    16  ???                                 0x00000001102e73cb 0x0 + 4566447051
    17  ???                                 0x00000001102ddedb 0x0 + 4566408923
    18  ???                                 0x00000001102dc8d3 0x0 + 4566403283
    19  ???                                 0x000000010b9f16d3 0x0 + 4489942739
    20  ???                                 0x000000010b9f1b9d 0x0 + 4489943965
    21  mlaunch                             0x000000010b5069a3 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1443
    22  mlaunch                             0x000000010b601c2f mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 127
    23  mlaunch                             0x000000010b608c4e mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 110
    24  mlaunch                             0x000000010b463de9 mono_jit_exec + 297
    25  mlaunch                             0x000000010b466dfa mono_main + 11178
    26  mlaunch                             0x000000010b4040ce xamarin_main + 1182
    27  mlaunch                             0x000000010b405044 main + 36
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6ecff3d5 start + 1
Entering thread summarizer from 123145522233344
Self-reporting for thread 123145522233344. Registered summarizing thread right now is 123145522233344
Waiting for signalled thread 123145522233344 to collect stacktrace. Status: MONO_SUMMARY_EMPTY
Self-reporting for thread 4594517440. Registered summarizing thread right now is 4594517440
2019-05-27 15:45:00.282 mlaunch[1639:177278] error: * Assertion at ../../../../external/mono/mono/mini/mini-exceptions.c:1405, condition `frame->ji && frame->type != FRAME_TYPE_TRAMPOLINE' not met

Application could not be uploaded to the device.
```

Comment: If you have upgraded your XCode to latest why not update your Visual Studio either?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT Now i update Visual Studio, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android to latest stable versions and i dont recieve this error. it's seems that are old.

Comment: Then you mean your issue has been fixed?

Comment: Yes , now all tools is up to date and working .

Comment: Glad you made it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw in the log has this: "This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 10.14.4."
I can fine the answer from: https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter/issues/303

> Xcode 10.2 compatible
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/2.2.7.2002-dev
>
> Xcode 10.2 compatible and allows NUnit 3
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/3.0.0-dev1

Comment: I found this issue but I dont use App Center